# Does Boost.Locale support reading and writing UTF-8 encoded files?

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8

It is the only reason I was excited about trying out Boost.Locale but there are no file I/O examples on the web site.
I am not sure if it means file I/O is not supported or suppoted but undocumented.
My platform is Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is such [an example](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/charset_handling.html):

```
std::locale loc= generator().generate("he_IL.UTF-8");
std::wofstream file;
file.imbue(loc);
file.open("hello.txt");
file << L"שלום!" << endl;
```

Also **Boost.Serialize** can [help to convert to UTF8](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html)

Comment: Note that Boost.Serialization's helper facet only converts between UTF-8 and UCS-4.